# Как увеличить строчное число?

Tags: php, mysql

Друзья, простите за банальный вопрос, в бд хранится число, к примеру: "0001" тип поля varchar, я хочу это число увеличить на 1, как это сделать?

мне нужно что бы нули сохранялись. Тоесть 0010, 0111 что то в этом роде, вообщем что бы нули сохранялись.

Comment: прибавьте как обычно и воспользуйтесь `lpad()` что бы дополнить ведущими нулями. А вообще не дело хранить в БД числа в таком формате. формат надо задавать уже при выдаче пользователю

Comment: спасибо за функцию! то что надо!